# Can Pandoc mark text inside a code block?

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I use `<mark>...</mark>` to highlight text in a Markdown document, such as the [Google Python Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html). I am having difficulty higlighting code. For example, I want to highlight how to annotate with types:

````
```python
<mark>def func(a: int) -> List[int]:</mark>
```
````

but this pandoc command:

```
pandoc -s -t html5 -o "Google Python style guide.html" "Google Python style guide.md"
```

shows `<mark>` and `</mark>` as code and does not render an HTML highlight.

One solution is to use a `pre` tag, such as:

```
<pre><mark>def func(a: int) -> List[int]:</mark></pre>
```

which does render an HTML highlight.

Can Pandoc render the HTML higlights without having to convert all ```python blocks to `pre` tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not by default. How is pandoc supposed to know the `<mark>` is not part of your code?

However, you can write a [pandoc filter](http://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) that matches on each code block and converts it to a raw html block. Something like (untested):

```lua
function CodeBlock(elem)
  html = "<pre>" .. elem.text .. "</pre>"
  return pandoc.RawBlock("html", html)
end
```

Note that you'll have to make sure you don't have other unescaped HTML in your code blocks.

**Update**

If you also want syntax highlighting, probably you want to try the [pandoc-emphasize-code filter](https://owickstrom.github.io/pandoc-emphasize-code).

Comment: I tested it and it works, thanks! This result is as if I had converted triple-quote code blocks to `pre` tags, so the HTML loses the syntax highlighting. I have never coded in Lua: can it filter the marks and still highlight the code in the block?

Comment: That seems hard to do, because you don't want the syntax-highlighter to take the `<mark>`s into account. Maybe you should use another approach like https://owickstrom.github.io/pandoc-emphasize-code/

Comment: This is very elegant and it works for position (though not yet for whole lines, see[GitHub issue](https://github.com/owickstrom/pandoc-emphasize-code/issues/8)). Are you able to make it work with Python syntax highlighting at the same time? I can get the Pandoc syntax highlighting or the HTML mark tags, but not both.

Comment: I decided for the pandoc-emphasize code filter as this approach is keeps syntax highlighting, offers precision with highlighting inside a line, and is the most maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

If you will always mark whole lines, then you can use CSS to do so.

The code block should be given an ID to make it easier to target it

````
``` {#types-demo .python}
def func(a: int) -> List[int]:
   return [a]
```
````

To highlight the first line, include this in your document:

````
```{=html}
<style>
#types-demo-1 {
    background-color: #ff0;
} 
</style>
```
````

Syntax highlighting should continue to work.

Comment: This is elegant and works if one wants to maintain as many CSS styles as different lines to highlight, e.g. with styles `#types-demo-N` for the `N`th line to highlight.